# Number picker dialog

Tags: android, widget

[image]

Does anyone know where can I find a tutorial or example on how to achive this kind of number picker dialog on android? I googled everything but only managed to find examples where you have to create your own buttons with custom images etc. Can this be done in simple way?

All I could find was this: http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5
but it doesn't quite help me.

Comment: This was a nice and good question, don't know why they closed it. Anyway, here's the best solution I've found: http://www.lukehorvat.com/blog/android-numberpickerdialogpreference/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are targeting API level 11 or higher, you can use [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)

If you are targeting earlier API levels, you will have to write your own NumberPicker or use one from a third party library.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDRsf7KX4rs) is a nice video tutorial.

Good luck!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much tutorials or examples on API level 11 NumberPicker, or am I searching in wrong places?

Comment: This link is broken now

Comment: I've updated the link in the answer with a more up-to-date video tutorial.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way you can go with this is to use [default Android NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

The way to design it like you want is to create your custom dialog and embed one of those in it such as:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View npView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker_dialog_layout, null);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Text Size:")
        .setView(npView)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
                })
            .create();
```

Comment: For newcomers: `R.layout.number_picker_dialog_layout` is just an android xml file with a number picker tag as root element you have to create yourself.

Comment: A bit more elaborate steps for creating the XML file for `R.layout.number_picker_dialog_layout` in Android Studio: Right click on your `layout` directory (left side Project pane). Select `New`. Select `Layout Resource File`. In the dialog box, type `number_picker_dialog_layout` in File name field. Type `NumberPicker` in the `Root Element` field. Done :)