# How to create a Dialog with a NumberPicker

Tags: android, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number picker dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800589/number-picker-dialog)

I want to create a dialog exactly like the first example Google gives here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

It's a simple control to pick a number, but I can't figure out which Widget it is..

[image: First dialog]

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800589/number-picker-dialog

Answer (score 0):

This is usually achieved by the [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) class with [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) inside.