# Use NumberPicker as Input Method instead of standard keyboard

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext

I have several EditText fields in my Activity. For one of those fields I like to use a NumberPicker to enter the values (e.g. age, height or whatever). Is there a possibility to display a NumberPicker instead of the keyboard once that specific editText is clicked?
I know that you can change the inputType to "text", "numberPassword" etc. in the layout file but I haven't found a possibility to make that inputType a customView.

Comment: This may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640917/number-picker-as-present-in-dialog-android

Comment: Do you have to use EditText? Maybe you could go on with a TextView or Button?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the input type of your edit text "None" and set focusable to false.

```
            <EditText
                android:inputType="none"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And in your java file, you can set an onClickListener in your edit text, where you can show NumberpickerView in a dialog or something and from there set the value in edit text. To show number picker as a dialog, you can refer to the stackoverflow link in the comment on your question.

Comment: That's what I finally came up with as a workaround. But as I'm using several edit Texts - some using the keyboard, some the picker - it would be a better user experience if the input views were in the same place.