# How to make Number Picker Dialog?

Tags: android, android-dialog

My Requirement is like whenever user select any number from number picker on that time that number should be printed on some text view and second time whenever user opens dialog again than previously selected number should be shown on that dialog

```
    ...
    ...

    view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    LinearLayout L = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout5);
    L.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showdialog();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
         Log.i("value is",""+newVal);
}

public void showdialog()
{
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(NameActivity.this);
    View npView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.multidialog, null);
    final NumberPicker firPicker = 
            (NumberPicker) npView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    firPicker.setMaxValue(9);
    firPicker.setMinValue(0);
    final NumberPicker secPicker = 
            (NumberPicker) npView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
    secPicker.setMaxValue(9);
    secPicker.setMinValue(0);
    final NumberPicker tirPicker = 
            (NumberPicker) npView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);
    tirPicker.setMaxValue(9);
    tirPicker.setMinValue(0);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("title");
    builder.setView(npView);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Set",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            view.setText(String.valueOf(firPicker.getValue() *100 
                    + secPicker.getValue() *10 + tirPicker.getValue()));
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        }
    });
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: can you paste your source code here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805040/android-how-to-create-a-number-picker-dialog

Comment: So it is showing default text everytime you open the dialog, Am I Correct ?

Comment: @user3363368: check out my answer does exactly wt u needed.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805040/android-how-to-create-a-number-picker-dialog

Comment: @user3363368: Check my new answer tested it and works fine

Answer (score 2):

```
public class sample extends Activity{

NumberPicker MyNumPicker1, MyNumPicker2, MyNumPicker3;
TextView txtMyText;
AlertDialog alertdialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);

    txtMyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMyText);
    txtMyText.setText("5");

    txtMyText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.numpicker, null);
                MyNumPicker1 = (NumberPicker) v1.findViewById(R.id.MyNunPicker1);
                MyNumPicker2 = (NumberPicker) v1.findViewById(R.id.MyNunPicker2);
                MyNumPicker3 = (NumberPicker) v1.findViewById(R.id.MyNunPicker3);

                MyNumPicker1.setMaxValue(20);
                MyNumPicker1.setMinValue(1);
                MyNumPicker1.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtMyText.getText().toString()));
                MyNumPicker1.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

                MyNumPicker2.setMaxValue(20);
                MyNumPicker2.setMinValue(1);
                MyNumPicker2.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtMyText.getText().toString()));
                MyNumPicker2.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

                MyNumPicker3.setMaxValue(20);
                MyNumPicker3.setMinValue(1);
                MyNumPicker3.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtMyText.getText().toString()));
                MyNumPicker3.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(sample.this);

                builder.setView( v1 );
                builder.setTitle("Select Number");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        int NumVal1 = MyNumPicker1.getValue();
                        int NumVal2 = MyNumPicker2.getValue();
                        int NumVal3 = MyNumPicker3.getValue();

                        txtMyText.setText(""+ ( (NumVal1 * 100) + (NumVal2 * 10) + NumVal3) );
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertdialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                alertdialog = builder.create();
                alertdialog.show();

            }
        });
}

}
```

here's the number_picker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/MyNunPicker2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/MyNunPicker3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/MyNunPicker2" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/MyNunPicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/MyNunPicker2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry for my reply late, I am using 3 number picker in dialog, how can I write it. can u give me the code, thank you.

Comment: wt shd be done with other 2 number picker? we can talk it out in [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49109/number-picker)

Comment: sorry, I can't talk in chat room, because it at least 20 reputation is needed, I have only 15 reputation.

Comment: Can't we talk in here?

Comment: The answer u wrote in here is what I want to do, but it is only for 1 number picker in dialog. I want to use in 3 number picker in dialog, I don't know how to write, can u give me the code.

Comment: do u want same functionality for other 2 Numberpicker?

Comment: yes, the same functionality for other 2 number picker. U can see my code at above.

Comment: which number picker's value shd be set to textview?

Comment: come in chat room I've just upvoted ur Q now u have 23 so lets talk it over der

Comment: I want to set all 3 number picker'value.                             eg. I select "3" in numberpicker1 , select "2" in numberpicker2 and select "5" in numberpicker3 , it will shown "325" in textview.