# How to show the hours only using Timepicker in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I've an application where I need to select the range of time interval in hours only and not the complete time as given by the native TimePicker.
How do we customize TimePicker to let us select and display only the hours format in android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214547/show-timepicker-with-minutes-intervals-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimePicker is a wrapper of NumberPicker. I hope the only idea is customize NumberPicker.
For instance, read this link: [How to create a number picker dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805040/how-to-create-a-number-picker-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android Wheel](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/). See [WheelView](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/demo/TimeActivity.java?r=16) implementation for Hours and Minutes selection.

So you would just need to keep one WheelView which will be for selection of hours. Like:

```
final WheelView hours = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.hourWheel);
hours.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 23));
hours.setLabel("hours");
hours.setLabelWidth(72);
```

And ignore the WheelView for Minute selection.

There are various Adapters, too, which includes [NumericWheelAdapter](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/adapters/NumericWheelAdapter.java?r=16) which would serve your purpose.  (Copying the whole code as it is below in case link may be broken in future.)

```
/*
 *  Copyright 2011 Yuri Kanivets
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

package kankan.wheel.widget.adapters;

import android.content.Context;

/**
 * Numeric Wheel adapter.
 */
public class NumericWheelAdapter extends AbstractWheelAdapter {

    /** The default min value */
    public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE = 9;

    /** The default max value */
    private static final int DEFAULT_MIN_VALUE = 0;

    // Values
    private int minValue;
    private int maxValue;

    // format
    private String format;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context the current context
     */
    public NumericWheelAdapter(Context context) {
        this(context, DEFAULT_MIN_VALUE, DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context the current context
     * @param minValue the wheel min value
     * @param maxValue the wheel max value
     */
    public NumericWheelAdapter(Context context, int minValue, int maxValue) {
        this(context, minValue, maxValue, null);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context the current context
     * @param minValue the wheel min value
     * @param maxValue the wheel max value
     * @param format the format string
     */
    public NumericWheelAdapter(Context context, int minValue, int maxValue, String format) {
        super(context);

        this.minValue = minValue;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < getItemsCount()) {
            int value = minValue + index;
            return format != null ? String.format(format, value) : Integer.toString(value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return maxValue - minValue + 1;
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a solution for this problem. Finally came up with this. An elegant solution, works as I wanted.

```
class HourPickerDialog(
        context: Context,
        timeSetListener: OnTimeSetListener,
        initialHourOfDay: Int,
        initialMinute: Int = 0,
        is24HourView: Boolean = true,
) : TimePickerDialog(context, timeSetListener, initialHourOfDay, initialMinute, is24HourView) {

    override fun onTimeChanged(view: TimePicker, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        onClick(this, BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        dismiss()
    }
}
```