# Create dialog like DatePicker

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I need to do a dialog like `DatePicker` or `TimePicker`, but the dialogue should display my data. Is this possible, or do I need to do a custom view for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I can't comment because I don't have enough rep.

There isn't a ready out of the box dialog that allows custom data to be set. I supposed the best approach would be to create a custom layout with a [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) and then set it as your dialog's view.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17806895/3990222) should point you to right direction.

Comment: Thx u, unfortunately my min sdk 9.