# Customized DateTimePicker android

Tags: android, datepicker, customization

I am working on Customized `DateTimePicker` in android , which shows Today , Tomorrow , Day after tomorrow as label,

Each day shows its own time slots

Like in `Grofers` app

I `googled`  for third party library , I couldn't find it .

Please help in this .

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom dialog with a your own view where you added a

```
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />
```

You can enter custom data into it, set the min and max values for day that would be 0 and 2 and then set the display values which is a simple string array. For more info about the numberpicker see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805040/how-to-create-a-number-picker-dialog

Answer (score 0):

There is third-party library called `DateTimePicker` contains a beautiful DatePicker, check it out

[Datetimepicker](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker)

You also can create custom Date Time Picker here
[custom Date Time Picker](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html)

Answer (score 0):

for newer version you can follow this one

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker