# How to recieve length of time based input from user?

Tags: android, timer, timepicker

I am currently using a TimePickerDialog in order to receive a length of time to count down from. The problem is that I need it to be possible to select 0 hours and some number of minutes from the TimePicker. I have been unable to locate any information on how to modify the TimePickerDialog class in order to make this happen. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If easier methods (that still look good) of receiving length based input exist, any links or information would also be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for NumberPicker widget, It enables you to select a range of numbers including 0. Take a look at this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805040/how-to-create-a-number-picker-dialog)