# Using android timepicker as a number picker

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, picker

My general problem is that I need to set a preference with a number from a finite list using something like a step size of 10 (or whatever).  I know I can do this with the classic NumberPicker but I like the look of the TimePicker and was wondering if anyone has some idea of how to customize it to act as a more of a general number picker.  It's probably fine with 12 values but it would be even better if you could have an arbitrary number of choices.  Maybe there's a different widget that would get me something similar...

[Here's a crude mockup of a dialog example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2GpZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [How to create a number picker dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805040/how-to-create-a-number-picker-dialog)

you could set the timepicker to 24h format and get 1-24 range. But I wouldn't recommend it. The Bottom line is you pretty much need to design the xml and java class for your custom number picker.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll dig into that link to see if it'll work for me.  I'll accept this answer in a few more days to give a little more time to see if someone has a trick up their sleeve.