# Is there any sort of slider similar to this as a seekbar alternative?

Tags: android, slider, android-widget, android-seekbar

[image]

I want something like that but in a horizontal fashion that the user can slide and select a number from a range.

Comment: Check this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805040/how-to-create-a-number-picker-dialog