# Dialogue taking up entire screen

Tags: android

I am creating a dialogue with a number picker and a button but unfortunately it is taking up the entire screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

    android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/numberPicker1"
    android:text="Set" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how i am creating the dialogue

```
        final Dialog d = new Dialog(CreateShiftActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
    d.setTitle("NumberPicker");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.num_dialog);
```

Comment: Have you tried to put `wrap_content` for height and width on the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: @Shubham you can take a reference from here:  https://github.com/yash786agg/SpinnerIOS

Comment: @Shubham.. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17806895/4657385

Comment: @jampez77 yes that was my first call, but nothing seems to work. Also to add, on some devices the dialogue is not taking up the entire screen, on some it is

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your relative layout:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I suggest so use Constraint layout in future.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

try this whit Constraints:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set" android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AlertDialog` instead

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateShiftActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.num_dialog, null);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(convertView);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("NumberPicker");
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```